# Arguments ignored in Java Jar

Tags: ubuntu, jar, java, executable-jar

I'm running the following code on Ubuntu 10.10, using OpenJDK 1.6.0_18:

```
 package mypkg;
 public class MyTest {
   public static void main(final String[] args) {
     System.out.println(args.length + " argument(s)");
     for (final String arg : args) {
       System.out.println(arg);
     }
   }
 }
```

After compiling it into a Jar, I'm completely puzzled why executing the following command from the terminal returns `0 argument(s)`:

> java -jar mytest.jar this is a test

This is my interpretation of [the Java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), stating:

> java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ argument ... ]

I almost have the feeling that I'm entering a wrong command in the terminal. What gives?

**Edit:** the MANIFEST.MF contains:

```
Manifest-Version 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_18 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: mypkg.Starter
Class-Path: .
```

Comment: What does your jar's META-INF/MANIFEST.MF contain?

Comment: I've updated the OP. The Main-Class path is the same as the package declaration.

Comment: Wow. I feel like an idiot. It was the `Main-Class` after all: I was launching a different class that was handling the arguments, and passing them on (incorrectly) to the desired class.

Comment: @Rob You may use your comment as an answer and I will accept it, since this was actually what led to me finding the source of the problem.

Comment: Sometimes all it takes to figure out the problem is explaining your problem to other people. :) - Glad you figured it out.

Comment: I know *exactly* what you mean. I had already given it a shot with a colleague; we both overlooked it. \*facepalm\*

Comment: @Paul - Cool, thanks. I've added a brief answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the contents of your `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file; make sure your `Main-Class` is using the correct class.

Answer (score 2):

Your manifest specifies `mkpkg.MyTest` as the main class file, while the file you've actually posted has the name `mypkg.MyTest`.

Also, you specify a Classpath of "." in your manifest, which is superfluous at best, but probably leads to the problem you see (as you've probably got a directory named `mkpkg` in your local directory).

Comment: You've got a sharp eye; it was just a typo, but that was indeed the source of the problem. I've edited the OP to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

If you knew your main class you can do it without the -jar option.

```
java -classpath .:my_jar_file.jar; package.MainClass [arguments]
```

This is working for me on Debian Lenny.

Comment: Sure enough, this works (replacing `;` with `:`), but it's a workaround. Is this a bug in OpenJDK?